# Call Javascript Function on another page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to click a link on another page(I do not have access to that page) which loads a JS function.

So can I call that function from my page thru **a href=""**  or thru **onClick=""**

Comment: Hi User, it helps us to better answer your question if you can show a more clear example of what you're trying to do. Consider posting a small example that helps to clarify your goals. Good luck!

Comment: i need to call a function which resides in an iframe on another page. Sorry - I cannot get clearer than this- :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a function remotely from another page. Besides, you already left your page by then.

Unless...

- that other page is somehow loaded to your page (AJAX+CORS or AJAX+proxy server maybe) and it's contents parsed *on your page*.
- that other page has some logic that reads hashtags or query strings and executes corresponding functions. This *could* work inter-domain via iframes, as you are *indirectly* controlling the iframe via it's hash/query string.
- that other page could be loaded via iframes. iframes would work if *"I do not have access to that page"* meant that you just don't have access on the current subdomain but both *live on the same top domain*.

  [Subdomain iframe communications can work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/450960/575527). Pages on `example.com` and `subdomain.example.com` can talk to each other but `example1.com` and `example2.com` can't talk to each other because both live on different domains. See the other answer regarding the Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 2):

If it's on a different domain and you can't change its content, then you can't do it due to [the same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Sorry. You'll have to find a different way to achieve whatever you're trying to do.