# Display a podcast from a sub-domain

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, podcast

first time poster here so I hope I am doing this correctly.  I have been contracted by my church to redesign their website. (They've been dealing with a table layout for years.)

I am looking to display an RSS feed (with an audio file) on my website.  I am unable to use PHP or any other server-side language, it has to be done in JavaScript.

Due to the way our hosting is set up, all images and xml files are hosted on

> images.(mydomainname).com

and the page on which I looking to display the podcast is

> (mydomainname).com/sermons

as such, I have run into the problem of being unable to access the xml file with JavaScript.  For all the Googling I've done, it seems that my GoogleFu has failed me.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1, you did just fine in asking your question. Maybe this is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333532/cross-site-ajax-requests

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to drop another static file on your images domain, then I'd suggest [EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/). It's a cross-browser library which provides an a way to communicate (using only client script) between different domains. Caveat: you need to have control over both domains in order to make it work (where "control" means you can place static files on both of them).