# Ajax call works on one host but not on another

Tags: html, ajax, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy, cross-domain-proxy

I am making an ajax call to the UPS address validation webservice.

If i make the call from my application with this domain it works (`http://serverone.org/addrvalidator`)

But it doesn't work if i use the other domain or an ip address instead of the domain (`http://servertwo.org/addrvalidator`). 

Both the domain names are intranet only domains.

Any help appreciate, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this, probably this is the answer you were looking for:
[Cross-site AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333532/cross-site-ajax-requests)