# jquery | get html from other url

Tags: jquery, get

I want to get html code ( to parse it and some data put into DB ) and I have jquery code like:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.run', function(e) {
        var link = 'http://www.nhl.com/ice/gamestats.htm?season=20122013&gameType=2&team=&viewName=summary';
        $.get(link, function(data) {
            console.log("data: ");
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

But in console.log I dont see any data.. What Im doing wrong ? Thanks

Comment: what you want to do ? you want to get some Json data from the "www.wp.pl" url ? or from above link ?

Comment: wouldnt you be doing it on the server side not on the client side (js) ?

Comment: this error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.wp.pl/. Origin http://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: nhl.com ;) wp.pl was just for test.

Comment: ah I paste here getJson, I want to get HTML code og page.

Comment: i think you should be looking at jsonp http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-site AJAX requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333532/cross-site-ajax-requests)

Comment: which is your server side language?Why dont try to do this only with server side?