# Cross Site ajax request not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Hi I need to have two standalone projects one will be an MVC project and the other an WEB API project.Both will be placed in separate solutions.

My problem appears when I try to make ajax calls from the mvc project to the web api project and I ge this error:

> ```
> OPTIONS http://localhost:54599/api/Account/IsCurrentUserAuthenticated 405
> ```
>
> (Method Not Allowed) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5 OPTIONS
>   `http://localhost:54599/api/Account/IsCurrentUserAuthenticated` Origin
>   `http://localhost:61620` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
>   jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   `http://localhost:54599/api/Account/IsCurrentUserAuthenticated`. Origin
>   `http://localhost:61620` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

After a bit of research I came up with this filter that is added to the controllers to witch I need to make calls:

```
 public class AllowCrossSiteJsonWebApiAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        string rqstMethod = filterContext.ActionContext.ControllerContext.Request.Method.Method.ToUpperInvariant();

        if (rqstMethod == "OPTIONS" || rqstMethod == "POST")
        {
            filterContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS");
            filterContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type");
        }

        if (rqstMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            filterContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

ANd this is the call I am making from the client:

```
 function fetch(url) {
    xhrFields = {
        withCredentials: true // pass auth cookies to server over ajax req
    };

    var options = {
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-16",
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: xhrFields
    };

    return $.ajax(options);
}
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-site AJAX requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333532/cross-site-ajax-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use   `dataType: 'jsonp'` for crossdomain requests

Comment: You do not need JSONP for cross domain if it is set up correctly with CORS and the browser supports it.

Comment: @epascarello indeed. However as the question was titled "Cross Site ajax request not working" my answer fits this title.

Answer (score 2):

```
var options = {
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-16",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        xhrFields: xhrFields
    };
```

You need to use `jsonp` datatype while using cross domain.

Comment: JSONP has nothing to do with CORS which is what he is using. He should set the `crossDomain: true` flag.