# how to use fetch data using post method in ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am able load the data using RESTclient(POST Method only) in FireFox. but while development i am not able to load the data in jquery or ajax using post method.

URL is,
http://www.simplysalesjobs.co.uk/api/1/job/multipleSearch.json?consumer=job_platform&token=d77c335323636de4e415a50ecc09509a

can anyone help me. ?

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: you are hosting file in same server or different server?

Comment: I have to fetch the data from that server and i have to display it in HTML Page. But I am not able to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

Due to cross site issues, you usually cannot unless they support jsonp.
Take a look at this question/answer for more details and check with your 
api provider to see if they support jsonp.

[Cross-site AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333532/cross-site-ajax-requests)

You could however, use php and curl.
Set up a page on your server that uses php and curl to get the information from the url and and then use jquery/ajax to get data from that page ( on your server )it to your page.

Like a wrapper.

Comment: I can use . xml also Like   http://www.simplysalesjobs.co.uk/api/1/job/multipleSearch.xml?consumer=job_platform&token=d77c335323636de4e415a50ecc09509a

Comment: Right, but jquery/ajax does not play nicely with cross site requests for security reasons. Google cross site ajax requests or click the links to the right of this answer for more details. You should curl the request and ask your own server for the information.